# Yeoman/Grunt clean:dist task property undefined

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

I'm new to grunt and having trouble with the clean:dist task for grunt-contrib-clean. This is my code for the task.

```
clean: {
    dist: {
        files: [{
            dot: true,
            src: [
                '.tmp',
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
                '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*',
                '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/Procfile',
                '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/package.json',
                '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/web.js',
                '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/node_modules'
           ]
        }]
    },
    server: '.tmp'
},
```

When I run grunt build I get the following warning "An error occurred while processing a template (Cannot read property 'dist' of undefined). Use --force to continue." I'm thinking it must be a syntax error or something wrong with a plugin, but I don't know enough to keep figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, changing from <%= yeoman.dist %> to <%= config.dist %> solves the problem from me. Not sure when using yeoman.dist syntax is appropriate, but in any case I solved my own problem. So the solutions is...

```
clean: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      dot: true,
      src: [
        '.tmp',
        '<%= config.dist %>/*',
        '!<%= config.dist %>/.git*',
        '!<%= config.dist %>/Procfile',
        '!<%= config.dist %>/package.json',
        '!<%= config.dist %>/web.js',
        '!<%= config.dist %>/node_modules'
      ]
    }]
  },
  server: '.tmp'
},
```